# Why does the tag in suggested edit review contains vote count?

Tags: discussion, tags, review-queues, design

This is one of my first tag wiki edit reviews, and I was a bit surprised about it containing a `vote` count display:

[image]

Is there a feature that allows voting for tags that I've been ignoring all this time? Is this due to reuse of a general template?

<sup>Note: Being not sure if this is a bug, I don't tag it as a bug. If you think that it's one, feel free to add it.</sup>

Comment: They are part of the Posts table, if I remember correctly, with an special PostType.

Comment: It shouldn't show irrelevant information in the UI though, regardless of the DB structure..